# Objective-C macro to detect if variable is primitive

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm looking a macro to detect if a variable is an object or a primitive in Objective-C.

In this context, I know the parameter must be a variable and will never be an expression.

Here is the best thing I've come up with:

```
#define IS_OBJECT(x)    ( @encode(__typeof__(x))[0] == '@' )
#define IS_PRIMITIVE(x) ( !IS_OBJECT(x) )
```

Usage:

```
NSString *testString = @"test";
NSString *nilString = nil;
NSInteger testInteger = 1;

STAssertTrue(IS_OBJECT(testString), @"IS_OBJECT(testString) must be YES");
STAssertTrue(IS_OBJECT(nilString), @"IS_OBJECT(nilString) must be YES");
STAssertFalse(IS_OBJECT(testInteger), @"IS_OBJECT(testInteger) must be NO");
```

There must be a better way.

---

**Update**

Considering @ChrisDevereux comment, I updated the IS_OBJECT macro.

```
#define IS_OBJECT(x) ( strchr("@#", @encode(__typeof__(x))[0]) != NULL )
```

It now passes:

```
NSString *testString = @"test";
NSString *nilString = nil;
NSInteger testInteger = 1;
Class classTest = [NSString class];

STAssertTrue(IS_OBJECT(testString), @"IS_OBJECT(testString) must be YES");
STAssertTrue(IS_OBJECT(nilString), @"IS_OBJECT(nilString) must be YES");
STAssertFalse(IS_OBJECT(testInteger), @"IS_OBJECT(testInteger) must be NO");
STAssertTrue(IS_OBJECT(classTest), @"IS_OBJECT(classTest) must be YES");
```

I still don't like this answer, and hope there is something slicker. Is there something in the runtime library which does this?

Comment: I think that your way of doing it is already nice.

Comment: Don't forget to check for '#', which represents Class

Comment: Shouldn't`NSInteger` be `false` ?

Comment: @yinkou The test is correct, only the message was misleading.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way using C11's [generic selection mechanism](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html). `_Generic` is standard (modern) C and supported in clang for a while.

```
#define IS_OBJECT(T) _Generic( (T), id: YES, default: NO)
```

It feels a bit less runtime-ish to me so I prefer it over the `@encode` way. But to be honest I just used it for this answer because I love the power `_Generic` gives to macros and think more people should start using it. If you don't know it you should read Robert Gamble's article linked above.

Comment: Did I just say I want people to write more preprocessor magic? UNDO! UNDO!

Comment: `IS_OBJECT(testString)` and `IS_OBJECT(nilString)` both failed. I'm not sure if this mechanism can used here.

Comment: I even tried `#define IS_OBJECT(x) ( _Generic((x), NSString *: YES, default: NO) )` and that didn't work either. This doesn't seem to work at all with Objective-C.

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be a compiler bug. I posted the issue on the llvm bug tracker.

Comment: I confirm, IS_OBJECT(testString) and IS_OBJECT(nilString) both fail.

Comment: I tried it as well and found that `IS_OBJECT([[NSString alloc] init])` does work. Even `IS_OBJECT(testString = [[NSString alloc] init])` works as expected. I have no idea why bare variables don't.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe That's a technique that I wouldn't have guessed myself. Learned something new.